# Stop text moving html

Tags: html, css

I have css & html code which I made to overlap an image, it worked perfectly until I received a complaint from my client.. The overlapping text moves when the browser is downsized. I see no problem with my code and research has proven futile. He said he wants it fixed ASAP, so I seek help from my fellow overflowers!
 
***CSS***

```
      p.contactInfo {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        right: 475px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    p.contactInfo span {
        color: #D7D7D7;
        font-size:13px;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        padding: 10px;
        float:right;
    }
```

***HTML***

```
                    <p class="contactInfo"><span>*******
                                                </span></p>
```

***DEMO***
http://jsfiddle.net/baGjv/

Comment: If you seek help, please provide a demo that shows the problem. And never write ASAP in your question.

Comment: Set the distance from the left edge not the right, the right edge isn't static so when you move it the text moves with it.

Comment: You would have to use a value like 35% because if not it is set by pixels and screens have different pixel amounts. A percent value would be the same on all screens. If all else fails use position:relative; and give it a location in the code.

Comment: I've added a demo, for those who want one. I'll be checking out these other comments on my code.

Comment: Using distance from the left side, it merely moved it to the left when I resized it.. Not very practical.

Comment: Any answers other than comments would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a set number such as 20px, it will be 20px on the screen, because screens are different sizes it will be different like this... imagine that this "$" is the element positioned 20px from the left. (I'm using left imagining that your template is centered which I can't be completely sure at this point if it would be)

```
large monitor
-----------------
  $


-----------------

small monitor
----------
  $


----------
```

It will be the same from the left but if you mess around with % values it will be completely different and stretch to each monitor. "$" given 20%. This will help if the rest of your page is static (like most are) and will stay aligned with the rest of your page. I am not saying `left:20%;` is the exact % you need, you'll need to change it.

```
large monitor
-----------------
    $


-----------------

small monitor
----------
  $


----------
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Spencer, the issue is that you are using `right: 475px` as your positioning. When your client resizes their browser to be -narrower- than `475px`, your item actually disappears off the left edge of the page, because the location of "`475px` from the right" is now no longer within the browser's display area.

My guess is that you are assuming that the page will always be at least, say, `600px` wide, even on the smallest usable browser someone will open it in. If this is the case, one way you can correct this is to set the `body` tag to have a `min-width` of `600px` (or whatever your minimum-width is). By doing this - you will create a scrollbar in the browser when the window gets too narrow - but not lose visibility.

The probably better way to solve your problem, though, is to *avoid using absolute positioning* in this manner. Absolute positioning is generally best-used *relative* to a relatively positioned element. See [this article](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) for a clear explanation of what I'm referring to.